# jQuery Post Returns Page Source (laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'd like to post a route and log the returned data. But it seems data returns the current page html.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#approvalButtonID').click(function(){
        $.when(
            $.post("myRoute", function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })
        ).then(function(){
            //location.reload();
        });
    });
});
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('myRoute', array(
    'as' => 'myRoute',
    'uses' => 'myController@myFunction'
));
```

**mycontroller.php**

```
public function myFunction(){
   return 'KyloRenIsAKiller';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your console.log() throws an error??

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using??

Comment: @Jorge Mejia console log returns the current page html. Does not return any errors. I'm using laravel 4.2.

Comment: 'uses' => 'myController@myFunction' check if the name of your controller and function are correct (case sensitive)

Comment: double checked, even created a new function for that which doesn't change the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the normal HTML submit is happening after your jQuery .click handler.  So the form POSTs, and if you have no action specified it will post to the current page, which will likely just return the same current page, which explains what you're seeing.

Try adding:

```
$('#approvalButtonID').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... rest of your code
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: What does Dev tools show, is the POST really going to `myRoute`, or the current page?  Any errors on the console?  Try removing the `$.when` and `$.then` to find the simplest possible case.

Comment: POST does not even reach to myRoute. No errors thrown on console. Just html output of the current page. Removed $.when and $.then, even replaced $.then with .done(). Actually i solved the problem without using jQuery, but it'd be good to know what the real problem is. Working on it.

Comment: If the POST isn't going to myRoute, your JS isn't firing.  Try putting another `console.log('clicked')` inside your click handler but outside the `$.post()` there to verify if it is being reached.  Is your selector matching correctly? You don't need `$.when`, `$.then`, or `$.done` to do a `$.post` so leave them out until it works and you need them.  Post your updated code.

Comment: my JS is firing. Because console.log('test') dumps "test" on console screen. I tested adding console.log('test') just before $.post() request.

Comment: OK I'm stumped :-)  Your original code, minus the $.when and $.then, and with the `e` and `e.preventDefault();` work fine.  [Here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/9hzomLza/), watch Dev tools.  myRoute doesn't exist obviously, but you can see the POST hits it.